# Can't able to write content to internal filesDir in androidTest environment

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

While doing Instrumented test, file operations are always throwing `IOException`. Detailed explanation below.

I've some file content in `test/resources` directory. For some reason, I need to copy this content from test/resources -> internal storage (`/data/user/0/package/files`).

I can able to read the content from the resource directory via this API (`javaClass.classLoader?.getResourceAsStream`) but when I write the content to the internal filesDir(`/data/user/0/package/files/file.txt`), it throws IOException.

Any ideas?

Update:

Code sample

```
val inputStream = javaClass.classLoader?.getResourceAsStream("file_name") //works fine
val fileContent = Okio.buffer(Okio.source(inputStream!!)).readUtf8() //Also works fine
FileUtils.writeFile(filePath, fileContent) //Throws FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That would include the test code that is failing and the complete stack trace for the `IOException`.

Comment: I was executing the below code and it throws FileNotFoundException
`FileUtils.writeFile(file_path, content)`

Answer (score 0):

Pass a file object to `writeFile`

```
val file = File(filePath)
FileUtils.writeFile(file, fileContent)
```

Comment: Actually FileUtils has both file object and file path APIs. I've tried different Utils also but none of them worked.